# Log4j logger.throwing cannot set log level

Tags: java, logging

I have some confusion about how to use logger.throwing in Apache Log4J to log an exception using specific log level.

logger is an instance of org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

This works fine:

```
return logger.throwing(new Exception("Message"));
```

This does not work. Why?

```
return logger.throwing(Level.DEBUG, new Exception("Message"));
```

Here is the error the compiler shows:

```
[javac]     return logger.throwing(Level.DEBUG, new Exception("Message"));
[javac]                                  ^
[javac]     method Logger.<T#1>throwing(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,T#1) is not applicable
[javac]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
[javac]         (argument mismatch; org.apache.log4j.Level cannot be converted to org.apache.logging.log4j.Level))
[javac]     method Logger.<T#2>throwing(T#2) is not applicable
[javac]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
[javac]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[javac]   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
[javac]     T#1 extends Throwable declared in method <T#1>throwing(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,T#1)
[javac]     T#2 extends Throwable declared in method <T#2>throwing(T#2)
```

Comment: `org.apache.log4j.Level cannot be converted to org.apache.logging.log4j.Level` specify the full package name of Level.

Comment: @Compass yes that was the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two implementations of Level in Log4j. One is older and won't work with this, as it is from an older log4j major version.

[Older implementation of org.apache.log4j.Level from 2012, for Log4j 1.2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html)

[The newer implementation is org.apache.logging.log4j.Level from 2017, for Log4j 2.X](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html)

If possible, remove all references to the old `Level` and use the newer implementation, or hard-declare the full package name.